# python - How to use in order traverse to compare trees

Tags: python, recursion

The question asks to use in order traverse to check if tree `q` and `p` are the same. My logic is:

1. when checking p and q's left and right, return False if q has a left/right child but p does not have one
2. when checking p and q's value, return False if they are not the same

I found in example: (BFS order)

p = [1,2,3,5,6]

q = [1,2,3,4,6]

It found the difference but still returns True. I kinda understand it is because it only call `inOrderTraverse()` in the recursion so the `return` command does not stop the recursion from running. I tried to add the `return` before recursion part so it becomes `return inOrderTraverse()`. However, in this case the recursion stops once all left children have been visited.

So I dont really know what other change could I make to get this thing work. Please help, thank you!

```
def inOrderTraverse(p, q):

     if p.left:
         if q.left and p.left.val == q.left.val:
             inOrderTraverse(p.left, q.left)
         else:
             return False

     if p.val != q.val:
         return False

     if p.right:
         if q.right and p.right.val == q.right.val:
             inOrderTraverse(p.right, q.right)
         else:
             return False

     return True
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  Neglecting this is bad form in any language, but inexcusable in Python.  Also, you should add your actual test cases for the trees rather than just describing them in list form.

Comment: You are ignoring the return values from the recursive calls.

Comment: You need return statements on the recursive call results, otherwise you're just throwing them away and returning `True` via the fall-through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides ignoring the return value of the recursive calls to `inOrderTraverse()`, as noted in the comments, you seem to be missing the case where `q.left` exists but `p.left` doesn't (ditto right).  Here's my rework of your code to address these two issues:

```
def inOrderTraverse(p, q):

    if p.left or q.left:
        if p.left and q.left:
            if not inOrderTraverse(p.left, q.left):
                return False  # sub trees don't match
        else:
            return False  # only one has left

    if p.val != q.val:
        return False  # vals don't match

    if p.right or q.right:
        if p.right and q.right:
            if not inOrderTraverse(p.right, q.right):
                return False  # sub trees don't match
        else:
            return False  # only one has right

    return True  # everything matches
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to returning the recursive values, the logic can be simplified a bit:

```
def areEqual(p, q):

  return bool(p) == bool(q) and (p is None or areEqual(p.left, q.left) and p.val == q.val and areEqual(p.right, q.right))
```